# How to prevent app switcher trying to display snapshot with same orientation

Tags: ios, uikit, uiapplication

I'm having trouble figuring out how to tell the app switcher to use the last snapshot taken, regardless of the orientation. Do you know how to do that?

For example, if I leave my app in landscape mode and open an app that's running in portrait, the app switcher doesn't display the last taken snapshot (which in this case would look rotated 90º). Instead it shows me a snapshot of the last time my app was in portrait mode.

Thanks

Comment: Interesting question. But I doubt there is anything you can do about that behaviour. Do you have an example of an app where the behaviour you desire is already in place?

Comment: Sure. Try Apple's own Video app. EA Sports games seem to all be able to do that as well.